Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props
I am using NextJS version 14 with PostgreSQL vercel
And here is my component:
src/app/dashboard/admin/categories/page.tsx
const Page = () => {
  const onHandleLevelCategoryChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const level = e.target.value as string;
    const result = fetchCategoryByLevel(level);
  };



  return (
    <form action={executeCreateCategory}>
      <div className="space-y-12">
        <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
          <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900">
            Tạo danh mục sản phẩm
          </h2>
          <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
            {/* title */}
            <div className="sm:col-span-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="title"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Tên danh mục sản phẩm
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-md">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    autoComplete="title"
                    className="block flex-1 border-0 bg-transparent py-1.5 pl-1 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    placeholder="Đầm nữ"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* description */}
            <div className="col-span-full">
              <label
                htmlFor="description"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Mô tả
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <textarea
                  id="description"
                  name="description"
                  rows={3}
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                  defaultValue={""}
                />
              </div>
              <p className="mt-3 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
                Viết 1 vài mô tả về danh mục sản phẩm này
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
          <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900">
            Phần thông tin thiết yếu
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
            Mỗi loại sản phẩm phải có cấp bậc và thuộc 1 loại sản phẩm nào đó
            nhất định vd: Điện thoại Nokia thuộc loại sản phẩm Điện thoại
          </p>
          <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
            {/* parent_id*/}

        <div className="sm:col-span-2">
          <label htmlFor="customer" className="mb-2 block text-sm font-medium">
          Thuộc loại sản phẩm
          </label>
          <select
            className="peer block w-full cursor-pointer rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-2 pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
            name="level"
            id="level"
            onChange={onHandleLevelCategoryChange}         
          >
            <option value={1}>Cấp 1</option>
            <option>Cấp 2</option>
            <option>Cấp 3</option>
            <option>Cấp 4</option>
          </select>          
            </div>
            <div className="sm:col-span-2">
              <label
                htmlFor="parent_id"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Loại sản phẩm cha
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <select
                  id="parent_id"
                  name="parent_id"
                  autoComplete="parent_id"
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                >
                  <option value={1}>Cấp 1</option>
                  <option>Cấp 2</option>
                  <option>Cấp 3</option>
                  <option>Cấp 4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Page;

src/app/lib/action.ts
const FormSchema = z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    level: z.string(),
    parent_id: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
});
   
export async function executeCreateCategory(formData: FormData){

    const { title, level, parent_id ,description } =  FormSchema.parse({
        title: formData.get('title'),
        level: formData.get('level'),
        parent_id: formData.get('parent_id'),
        description: formData.get('description')   
    })
    let p_result :number = 0 ;   
    try {
        const result = await sql`call pro_createcategory(${title}, ${level}, ${parent_id},${description},${p_result})`;
        const isSuccess:boolean = result.rows[0].p_result > 1 ? true : false    ;
        return isSuccess;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("dashboard/admin/categories - executeCreateCategory - FALSE");       
    }
}


src/app/lib/data.ts
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";
import { TCategory } from "./definitions";

export async function fetchCategoryByLevel(level: string) {
  try {
    const levelConvertedNumber  = Number(level);
    const data = await sql<TCategory>`
       call pro_getcategorybylevel(${levelConvertedNumber})
      `;
    console.log("data: ", data);

    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Database Error:", err);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch all customers.");
  }
}

Here I have executed the stored procedure call 2 times and it has failed
->Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
<select className=... name="level" id=... onChange={function onHandleLevelCategoryChange} children=...>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.
Please help me ..
Please help me or give me some advice for this problem
